# React native useState and return statement not working together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here whenever i click  the icon it doesnt show anything. It supposed to be showing some text and when clicked again it should hide the text. Im using react native.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default function Edit(props, { navigation }) {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setSlide(!slide);
    console.log('clicked');
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>random</Text>
        <Text>random</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
return (
  <View>
    <FontAwesome name="sliders" size={30} color="#000" onPress={() => toggle()}/>
  </View>
}
```

After testing the only thing it shows is the console.log('clicked') message. It does not display anything else. Also the icon displays normally. Everything is working except the  and the content in those tags.

Comment: you are missing a closing `)`after `</View>`

Comment: I forgot to put in when writing question. in real code i checked and saw it there but thank anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than returning the `View` from your `toggle` function, you actually need to display that view your view hierarchy (eg what is returned from your component).

I've demonstrated in the example by using a ternary expression -- if `slide` is `true`, it gets shown, otherwise it does not.

```
export default function Edit(props, { navigation }) {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setSlide(!slide);
    console.log('clicked');
  }
return (
  <View>
    <FontAwesome name="sliders" size={30} color="#000" onPress={() => toggle()}/>
    {slide ? <View>
        <Text>random</Text>
        <Text>random</Text>
      </View> : null}
  </View>
  );
}
```

Snack example: https://snack.expo.io/7lVezwWs7